# How to debug ECS Fargate Healthcheck fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

How do I debug failed healthcheck errors on ECS. The question is very vague because I don't get much from AWS in terms of error logs.

The only information I have is when I run my Fargate service task, I get:

`Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group TARGET_GROUP_NAME)`

The logs in the container aren't much more useful:

`4/10/2023, 7:04:52 PM [2023-04-10 15:04:52 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term backend 4/10/2023, 7:04:28 PM [2023-04-10 15:04:28 +0000] [67] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 67 backend 4/10/2023, 7:04:28 PM [2023-04-10 15:04:28 +0000] [1] [WARNING] Worker with pid 63 was terminated due to signal 9 backend 4/10/2023, 7:04:27 PM [2023-04-10 15:04:27 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:63) backend 4/10/2023, 7:03:57 PM [2023-04-10 15:03:57 +0000] [63] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63`

I'm certain of my ports/ALB configuration/Target group configuration since my task was running perfectly fine before I deployed my latest changes for my docker container. My docker works on my local machine. There weren't even any major changes.

I am also unable to ping my endpoint.

I understand this is vague, I'm not looking for a resolution just looking for how do I even start to debug this as there are absolutely no useful logs anywhere.

I have tried deploying my previous docker container and everything worked fine, which proves that my ALB/Target Group/Ports...etc are all configured correctly.

Comment: If you check the target group in the AWS console, it should show the reason for the health check failure (eg timeout, wrong response code, etc)

Comment: Thank you, I see: Request timed out. But that still doesn't help. I can run my docker on my machine, and this all used to run exactly as is with the current configurations, only thing that changed is my docker.

Comment: Judging by the error in your logs: `[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT` it appears that something is going on with your application such that it isn't responding in a reasonable time, so your server (gunicorn?) is timing out. Whatever is causing that doesn't seem related to ECS specifically. Perhaps you need to increase the log level of your application to debug this better. As far as ECS is concerned it is sending requests to your container, and your container isn't responding. There's not much more ECS can tell you. You need to look into the container processes.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's exactly it. It was a SQL connection timing out and holding up the application.